# Django: Username is empty when a new user is created when signing in

Tags: python, django

I have made custom forms for log in and registration in Django using HTML/CSS and not Django's form.as_p. I have the following code in views.py:

```
def login_user(request):
logout(request)
if request.POST:
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('/mainpage/')
    else:
        login_message = "Your username or password is incorrect."
        return render(request, 'index.html', {'login_message': login_message})
return render(request, 'index.html')

def sign_up(request):
    if request.POST:
        username = request.POST['username']
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']
        password_confirm = request.POST['password-confirm']
        if(valid_form(username, email, password, password_confirm)):
            #create the new user
            user = CustomUser(name=username, email=email, password=password)
            user.save()
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/mainpage/')
        else:
            message = "There was a problem."
            return render(request, 'index.html', {'message': message})
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

I have the following model for CustomUser in models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
email = models.EmailField(max_length=70, null=True)
password = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
```

My code is working for the sign up and I can create a new user after inputting the username, email and password. When I check the users in the user list on the Django admin site, for the new user I created (ruby), only their email is stored and not their username. I believe this is the reason I am also having trouble logging in with this new user.

[image]

However I am not sure why the username isn't being stored for the new user I created. Any insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the issue is here:

```
user = CustomUser(name=username, email=email, password=password)  # <-- Here
user.save()
```

You are not storing the `username` here. I think its better to do it either:

```
user = CustomUser(name=username, email=email, username=username)
user.set_password(password)  # otherwise the password will be stored in plain text
user.save()
```

Or you can use [**`create_user`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user) manager method to create Users.

Answer (score 1):

According to django doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/contrib/auth/models/, AbstractUser has username field which is required and used for authentication:

```
username = models.CharField(_('username'), max_length=30, unique=True,
        help_text=_('Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and '
                    '@/./+/-/_ only.'),
        validators=[
            validators.RegexValidator(r'^[\w.@+-]+$',
                                      _('Enter a valid username. '
                                        'This value may contain only letters, numbers '
                                        'and @/./+/-/_ characters.'), 'invalid'),
        ],
        error_messages={
            'unique': _("A user with that username already exists."),
        })
```

In your case, you have a `name` field which is an additional field in the model, but in the `views`, you are passing username to name, while the required `username` field is not filled up.

Try to remove 'name' field in the model. Pass username to `username`

Answer (score 0):

Since your 'CustomUser' class extends AbstractUser (which provides the full implementation of the default User as an abstract model), you should use the same signature (`username`, instead of `name`) as follows:

```
#create the new user
user = CustomUser(username=username, email=email, password=password)
```